# Determine function to execute from option used

Tags: python, function, scripting

How can options/arguments determine which function is chosen during program execution? For the example I have two options depending on the option I would like them to use their respective functions. What am I missing?

```
import os, sys, glob
from optparse import OptionParser

def fname(arguments):
    files = []
    for arg in arguments:
        if '*' in arg or '?' in arg:
            # contains a wildcard character
            files.extend(glob.glob(arg))
        elif os.path.isdir(arg):
            # is a dictionary
            files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(arg, '*')))
        elif os.path.exists(arg):
            # is a file
            files.append(arg)
        else:
            # invalid?
            print '%s invalid' % arg
    return files

# check if file exists locally, if not: download it
def downnload(filename, keyString):
    if not os.path.exists(filename+keyString):
        l.get_contents_to_filename(filename+keyString)

# List bucket contents
def blist(bucket):
    for b in rs:
        print b.name

def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] -f filename"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option('-d', '--download',
            action='store', dest='download',
            default=None, help='download files from cloud')
    parser.add_option('-l', '--list',
            action='store', dest='bucket',
            default=None, help='list buckets or contents of specified bucket')

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    # from boto import
    bucket_list = bucket.list()
    for l in bucket_list:
        keyString = str(l.key)

    downnload(options.filename, keyString)
    blist(options.bucket)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You are missing a lot.</strike>

1. Where is `filename` given a value?
2. Where is `keyString` given a value?
3. Where is `bucket` given a value?
4. You shouldn't name your function `list` since that it is a primitive type

You probably want to look at the [`optparse` tutorial](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html?highlight=optparse#tutorial).  I'm assuming that you expecting `bucket` to receive the value from the `--list` command line argument.  The value gets stored into `options.bucket` instead.  That is just a start.

I think that you want to change the end of `main` to check the options and call the appropriate function.  Something like:

```
def main():
    # much omitted
    if options.filename is not None:
        downnload(options.filename, keyString)
    elif options.bucket is not None:
        blist(options.bucket)
    else:
        print 'Either --download or --list is required.'
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(-1)
```

I think that this is what you are looking for.  It decides which function to call based on the command line arguments passed in.  For example, if the user passes `--download filename` then the `downnload` function is called with the supplied filename as the argument.

Comment: I've added more relevant code, changed list to blist updated the functions to use options.x, can arguments be optional for some options and required for others?

Comment: I didn't notice the last part of your question.  Yes, take a look at the ["Handling boolean options" section](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html?highlight=optparse#handling-boolean-flag-options)